# Database schema for multiple category/product relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I want to design a database for an e-commerce application with category/subcategory management. Please suggest a **database schema** where we can create categories and subcategories and add products to those categories. **Each product can have multiple categories and we can select products belong to multiple categories using a boolean database query**

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For categories and sub-categories to any level, along with products belonging to multiple categories, I would start with:

```
Categories:
    category_id
    parent_category_id foreign key (Categories.category_id)
    ... other category information ...
    primary key (category_id)
Products:
    product_id
    ... other product information ...
    primary key (product_id_id)
ProductCategories:
    product_id foreign key (Products.product_id)
    category_id foreign key (Categories.category_id)
    primary key (category_id,product_id)
    index (product_id)
```

This way you can reach your goal of a hierarchy of categories as well as achieving a many-to-many relationship between products and categories.

---

You can select a product ID belonging to multiple categories (e.g., 3 and 4) with a query like:

```
select a.product_id
from Products a, Products b
where a.product_id  = b.product_id
  and a.category_id = 3
  and b.category_id = 4
```

Comment: how to get the products with two category_id  for example  3 and 4 ?

Comment: See update: the old-school way: select a.product_id from Products a, Products b where a.product_id = b.product_id and a.category_id = 3 and b.category_id = 4. There's no doubt a more "modern" way as well though a decent DBMS should optimise them equally.

Answer (score 0):

This would be best solved with a join table.  That is, you have a `products` table, and a `categories` table, each with a primary key.  Then, you create a third table, which is the join table.  It has 3 columns:  it's primary key, `category_id`, and `product_id`.  Then, when you want to add a relationship between a product and a category, you insert a row into the join table with the `category_id` and `product_id` that are related.  You can then use the 3 tables together with joins to display the relationships.